# How can i solve "pyttsx3 errors" on macos?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

i am making voice assistant in python. I found example in youtube. Then i try it but when i run this code i am getting errors. Pyttsx3 can't runnning. I can't find solution. I need help. I am using MacBook M2.

Here's my code:

```
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)

engine.runAndWait()

def input_instruction():
    global instruction
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as origin:
            print("I'm listening...")
            speech = listener.listen(origin)
            instruction = listener.recognize_sphinx(speech)
            instruction = instruction.lower()
            if "Jarvis" in instruction:
                instruction = instruction.replace('jarvis', '')
                print(instruction)

    except:
        pass


def play_Jarvis():
    instruction = input_instruction()
    print(instruction)
    if "play" in instruction:
        song = instruction.replace('play', "")
        talk("Playing " + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in instruction:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M%p')
        talk('Time is' + time)
    elif 'tarih' in instruction:
        date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d /%m /%Y')
        talk('Today's date' + date)
    elif 'how are you' in instruction:
        talk('Thanks boss and you?')
    elif 'what is your name' in instruction:
        talk('my name is Jarvis how can i help you')
    else:
        talk('Please repeat')

play_Jarvis()
```

Then i'm getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Users/akyel/PycharmProjects/sesliAsistan/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?
```

Please help me...

I reinstalled everything but i can't solved.

Comment: You could always [download](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/#files) the library from PyPI (python packaging index), since installing it from the cmd prompt doesn't seem to work for you (likely the devs of the package forgot to update some version).